# measurement, open quantum systems and wavefunction (un)-collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

Consider a TLS with Hamiltonian $H=-(1/2)\epsilon\sigma_z$

I then consider the open evolution of this system with a Lindblad equation of the form

$$d\rho = -i/\hbar[H,\rho]+\sum_{i=1}^2 L_i\rho L^\dagger_i -(1/2)\{L_i^\dagger L_i,\rho\}$$

where

$$L_1\propto|0\rangle\langle 1|$$
$$L_2\propto e^{-\epsilon\hbar\beta/2}|1\rangle\langle 0|$$

The Kraus representation over short times is then

$$\rho(t+dt)=\sum_{i=0}^{2}M_i\rho(t)M_i^\dagger$$

where

$$M_0=I-(i/\hbar)Hdt-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^2L^\dagger_i L_idt$$
$$M_1=L_1dt^{1/2}$$
$$M_2=L_2dt^{1/2}$$

A connection between a quantum jump unravelling and measurement is made by recognising that the probability of measuring  say the emission of a photon into the environment (or whatever) from a pure state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by

$$p_1= \langle\psi|M_1^\dagger M_1|\psi\rangle$$

This then connects with the idea that this is the probability of the jump associated with $L_1$ occurring: i.e. the quantum jump that takes the TLS from an arbitrary superposition $a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle\to|0\rangle$ occurring with probability $Tr(L^\dagger_1 L_1\rho)$ which is equivalent for a pure state.

Now this is a form of wavefunction collapse associated with a measurement of the system, right? We have destroyed a superposition and know exactly what state the two level system is? Is this correct?

If that is correct my follow on question is how to understand the non jump behaviour of this unravelling: when we are making making the 'measurement' that we observe no emission or absorption of a photon in the environment this corresponds to Kraus operator $M_0$. This naturally has probability of occuring $p_0=\langle\psi|M_0^\dagger M_0|\psi\rangle=1-\langle\psi|M_1^\dagger M_1|\psi\rangle-\langle\psi|M_2^\dagger M_2|\psi\rangle=1-p_1-p_2$. But associated with this Kraus operator is evolution from the eigenstate $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle $ to a superposition $c|0\rangle +d|1\rangle$ (if a jump has occurred previously) via the non-unitary dynamics of $M_0$. This appears to be uncollapsing the wavefunction into a superposition pure state (not a mixed state) without any physical interaction with the environment. How should I understand this?

Comment: $M_0$ commutes with $\sigma^z$ (check it!), so it will not change the populations of the energy eigenstates.

Comment: Sure, but in the quantum jump unravelling that I allude to the behavior associated with $M_0$ (which admittedly has extra terms over and above $M_0$ due to the mechanics of the unravelling) doesn't and causes the state to evolve away from the eigenstates. Right? How should I understand this?

Comment: I'm not sure which extra terms you are referring to. In the usual unravelling, $M_0-I$ is the generator of the "no-detection" evolution. It doesn't change the relative populations nor generate coherences. It only reduces the overall norm of the (conditional) state, corresponding to the decreasing probability that no photon is detected.

Comment: The unravelling I mean is seen in EQ 1.6 here http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.47.1652 It is non linear and I am literally simulating it and plotting the evolution on the Bloch sphere. The jumps occur like a poisson process with rate dependent on the state which take the state to the poles of the Bloch sphere, but in between the state moves away from the poles.

Comment: Ah, I made an error, apologies! You are correct!

Comment: As a follow on question, if you'll humor me, what is the implication of the situation if $H=\sigma_x$? Now M_0 doesn't commute with H and so 'non measurement' does change the state even if one starts in one of the eigenstates of the system, in contrast to the free Hamiltonian evolution which would maintain the state.